# Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11)

Tags: android, adt

I've been following the Android official training program, and on the lesson Managing the Activity Lifecycle » Starting an Activity, there is a piece of code that goes like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* ... some other stuff ... */

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

When I write it in my test application however, I get a warning from ADT saying

> Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11):
>   android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled

My app indeed is min API level 11, as it should be per the tutorial, but why is ADT acting so smug telling me this doesn't belong there, when the call to that method is inside a block that checks the current version? The training program continues to convince me that this is okay by saying:

> Caution: Using the SDK_INT to prevent older systems from executing new
>   APIs works in this way on Android 2.0 (API level 5) and higher only.
>   Older versions will encounter a runtime exception.

But avoiding a **runtime** error doesn't help much, when ADT doesn't even let me compile this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but why is ADT acting so smug telling me this doesn't belong there,
>   when the call to that method is inside a block that checks the current
>   version

Yes you added it but `IDE` know nothing about you are checking version through Build.

Just add **@SuppressLint("NewApi")** and error will disappear. Or you can create bellow methods and use them in conditions:

```
@TargetApi(14)
private void actionAPI14() {
   getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
}

private void action() {
   getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

Always you can use support package for lower API versions.

Comment: As I answered to the Abhishek Shukla below, I did add the support package in one of the previous lessons. If it should work with the support package, without suppressing errors from Lint, then there must be something else wrong... Your advice for suppressing Lint errors does get it running however, so I can at least continue with my lessons now :)

Comment: Note sure if this is totally clear, but in order to use the support action bar, you need to use getSupportActionBar() rather than getActionBar(). Using the latter will fail and throw an error on APIs lower than 14.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using the support jar for backwards support. It'll run on the lower APIs as well.

Comment: I am using the support jar, also from one of the previous lessons, and I have the line saying `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` which I suppose must be working fine as it is not reporting any errors.

Comment: Can you share the stackTrace her?

Comment: Not really, since it doesn't let me compile it at all, saying `Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.` If I add suppress Lint, then I get no errors.